# Position:fixed menu disappears when using bottom:0

Tags: html, css

Testing this on Chrome: I just want the menu to stick to the bottom left. It shows when I am NOT using `bottom: 0`. If I use `top` it works. What could be causing the issue?

```css
.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="mobile-menu">testing this menu</nav>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="main-logo">
      <object data="svg/main-logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <img src="fallback.jpg" />
      </object>
    </div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working.

Comment: What do you mean? Appears to be positioned in the bottom left corner to me.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `.wrapper` `position: relative` and `.mobile-menu` `position: absolute`. In order to illustrate your problem better, I added some content under your header. So the green menu = `good` and the red menu = `bad`.

**Solution**

- In the demo I have renamed your red menu to: `.mobile-menuOriginal`
- I have added an identical `.mobile-menu` and changed the `background-color: green` and `position: absolute`

**Reasons**

- `position: fixed` will place an element relative to the viewport, so a `bottom:0` will always place an element at the bottom of the screen.
- `position: relative` places an element in relation to it's original position, so by placing `.wrapper` in `position: relative` with no specific coordinates (i.e. `top`, `right`, `left`, and `bottom`), `.wrapper` stays where it is. The reason why `.wrapper` needs this is so it can be out of normal *flow*.
- `position: absolute` places an element in relation to it's parent, so by putting `.mobile-menu` into `absolute` positioning, it will position itself within the borders of `.wrapper` because `.wrapper` is `.mobile-menu`'s parent and *closest positioned* element. I mentioned *closest positioned* because there are some exceptions to what I said about positioned parents. Please refer to this [article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) before I confuse you.

**Edit**

@t.niese further explains:

> [...]*The reason why .wrapper needs this is so it can be out of normal flow.*[...] out of flow is a bit misleading, because element with position relative has only a visual displacement to the object, but it will still use the same space in the flow like before and will also be still be influenced by its surrounding in contrast to absolute which move the element out of flow.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: green;
}
.mobile-menuOriginal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="mobile-menu">testing this menu</nav>
    <nav class="mobile-menuOriginal">testing this menu</nav>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="main-logo">
        <object data="svg/main-logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
          <img src="fallback.jpg" />
        </object>
      </div>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>


  <section>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Byline</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `relative` puts the parent out of flow and into a reference for the menu which is absolutely positioned. OP didn't demo properly, because it's only a header, so you wouldn't see the menu drop any further than the header. OP should say that menu should be at the bottom of header not the bottom of screen.

Comment: Indeed, sir. I am in full agreement, but if anyone was reading my half formed answer, they should notice me editing as well. You process info too fast and accurately  ;-)

Comment: Well I can't see that you are editing ;) I just can see that the post only contains code. And with `3k` for sure also have seen many `Try this:` answers or even wrong answers just having code and no explanation.

Comment: Two minor notes: `[...]places an element in relation to it's parent[...]`  should bein relation to the closest **ancestor** that is positioned (later you write `closest positioned`  which is correct). `[...]The reason why .wrapper needs this is so it can be out of normal flow.[...]` out of flow is a bit misleading, because element with position `relative` has only a visual displacement to the object, but it will still use the same space in the _flow_ like before and will also be still be influence by its surrounding in contrast  to `absolute`which move the element out of flow.

Comment: Hence the last sentence: *Please refer to this [article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) before I confuse you.* Upped your comment for preciseness. :-)